# MisFormatted line exception - JWI on Android

Tags: java, android, wordnet, numberformatexception, jwi

I am trying to use the [Java-WordNet interface](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) on an Android project. I am able to make the basic code to open the dictionary etc. (as given in the docs work) which is also what I need in my own project. However, I notice that sometimes the `dict.open()` method will fail at run-time with an error whose stacktrace is given below:

```
   10-15 19:10:34.556: E/com.sriram.dict.EHDictionary@40516b00(16596): Run time exception caught.
    10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596): edu.mit.jwi.data.parse.ILineParser$MisformattedLineException: ��������Mac OS X        �������� ������2����ﾰ����������￢������������������������������������������������������������������������ATTR;ﾚ￉����￢������ﾘ������U������������������������������������ﾘ������U����com.apple.quarantine��0001;525b8927;Google\x20Chrome;774A992E-4B54-4DBA-AD26-44520094A014|com.google.Chrome��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������� < lots of these question marks> 
    ��������������������������
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.parse.DataLineParser.parseLine(DataLineParser.java:234)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.parse.DataLineParser.parseLine(DataLineParser.java:54)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.FileProvider.createDataSource(FileProvider.java:481)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.FileProvider.createSourceMap(FileProvider.java:431)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.FileProvider.open(FileProvider.java:318)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.DataSourceDictionary.open(DataSourceDictionary.java:92)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.CachingDictionary.open(CachingDictionary.java:133)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at com.sriram.dict.EHDictionary.initDict(EHDictionary.java:250)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at 
com.sriram.dict.EHDictionary.<init>(EHDictionary.java:50)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at com.sriram.dict.EHTextView.initEHTextView(EHTextView.java:83)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at com.sriram.dict.ContentHandler.onCreate(ContentHandler.java:84)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
        10-15 19:10:34.576: W/System.err(16596):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '��������Mac' as integer
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596):    at edu.mit.jwi.data.parse.DataLineParser.parseLine(DataLineParser.java:95)
        10-15 19:10:34.581: W/System.err(16596):    ... 23 more
```

And the code is:

```
try {
                    dict.open();
                    if(VERBOSE) Log.v(this.toString(), "Dictionary open.");
                    wns = new WordnetStemmer(dict);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "IOException in opening dictionary.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(RuntimeException e1) {
                    Log.e(this.toString(), "Run time exception caught.");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The error above seems to occur in cases where the dictionary is downloaded from a repository I have made available. Thinking it might be a case of something-lost-in-download, I added a checksum (with MD5) such that each time the app is loaded, this checksum is performed and then compared with a list of checksums for the various files in the dictionary (from files known to not give this error). The checksum matches each time.

My question(s):
1. What does the ???? in the error above indicate? Is there any way I can get to the text of it?
2. Any clues on solving this would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not because of JWI. Copying files from a Mac to a non-Mac system causes the OS to add resource fork files automatically. If you have a filename with name "file1.xyz", then Mac OSX will try to add a resource fork in the same directory with the name "._file1.xyz". The resource fork is a sort of metadata that helps render content on screen (font name, size etc.). On most *nix type OSes, any file with a "." in the beginning of the name will be hidden, causing it to not be seen. These files are what are causing the loading of the dictionary to fail.

There is no way around this except to delete the files from every single directory. This is a legacy Mac issue.

Comment: Sriram, I'd like to apologize for reviving a thread that is a couple of months old. Could you help me with integrating JWI into my android app. I've been struggling with the Rita wordnet jar and integrating it into android. How did you download the WordNet database files and add them to the android project? I'm kinda desperate and would accept any guidance

Comment: JWI is written in Java and is compatible with Android. I imported the jwi jar into the libs/ folder of the project and went through the sample project on the website.

Comment: So you did not import the WordNet Database files?

Comment: Of course you need to import the files too. Check out the sample code on the website. It will give you all you need to run JWI on Android.