# Copying files from unzipped folder - Mac OSX vs Windows

Tags: android, macos, copy-paste

I have an Android app that I am testing internally. To do so, I have set up a link to download the APK along with associated content which is essential for the app to run. The following are some of the steps I have taken:

1. Tar-balled the content on my machine which runs Mac OSX.
2. Sent it to the systems person who then un-tars it and zips it (a lot of the people on the team may not have tar utilities) and uploads it.
3. The tester downloads the file using a Windows machine and unzips it (using either WinRar or WinZip). The unzipped folder is put into a specific folder in the external storage directory of the Android smartphone.
4. The app, when started, fails immediately with a stacktrace that I have documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390429/misformatted-line-exception-jwi-on-android). The error is a MisFormattedLine Exception in the Java-WordNet interface that I am using for providing dictionary features for this app.
5. However, if I delete the content on the Android device, mount the device on my Mac, download the content from the same link and copy-paste the content into the same area, the app works just fine!!

To get to the root of the problem, I have also tried to do an MD5 of each of the files in the folder and compared it to a version of the content with which the app worked. There is no difference.

My question(s):
1. Is there some `copy` function behavior that varies between a Mac and Windows that I am missing?
2. What do I need to do in order to ensure that the files are copied correctly?

Comment: In my opinion, this is nothing to do with tarballing/copying/zipping.  I've spent a lot of time txfering stuff to/from OSX/Windows and never had an issue. That said, I do use stuffit on OSX since the built in tools are not very reliable. The trace looks like you are trying to read a binary file.  Focus instead on logging which files you are trying to read as content.  I suspect you will find something you didn't expect.

Comment: @Simon: Thank you for the reply. But the stacktrace as given in the other question does mention "Mac OSX" and Google Chrome. That should count for something, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not because of JWI. Copying files from a Mac to a non-Mac system causes the OS to add resource fork files automatically. If you have a filename with name "file1.xyz", then Mac OSX will try to add a resource fork in the same directory with the name "._file1.xyz". The resource fork is a sort of metadata that helps render content on screen (font name, size etc.). On most *nix type OSes, any file with a "." in the beginning of the name will be hidden, causing it to not be seen. These files are what are causing the loading of the dictionary to fail.

There is no way around this except to delete the files from every single directory. This is a legacy Mac issue. I have added this answer to the question linked to above.